# Jenkins run job with stashedfile parameter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I can run a new job from a different job with `build job: 'jobname'`
But my new job also requires a stashed file parameter. Can this be included in the
`parameters[]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing the parameter as a `io.jenkins.plugins.file_parameters.StashedFileParameterValue` worked for me. StashedFileParameterValue requires a `org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem` which also needs to be created. Also FileItem is not serializable, so it needs to be created in a `@NonCPS` method. Combining all of that together, a simple pipeline that calls a job, `stashed-file`, which has a `stashedFile` parameter named `INPUT_FILE`, looks like below:

```
@NonCPS
void triggerStashedFileJob(File testFile) {
    def factory = new org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory()
    def fileItem = factory.createItem('file', 'text/plain', false, 'test-copy.txt')
    fileItem.outputStream << testFile.bytes

    build job: 'stashed-file', parameters: [
        new io.jenkins.plugins.file_parameters.StashedFileParameterValue('INPUT_FILE', fileItem),
    ]
}

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('trigger job that needs stashed file') {
            steps {
                deleteDir() // To cleanup workspace 
                sh '''
                   echo "hello from parent job" >> test.txt
                '''

                script {
                    File testFile = new File("${env.WORKSPACE}/test.txt")
                    triggerStashedFileJob(testFile)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I believe I used something similar but completely forgot about this post. Surely it will help someone in the future :)

Answer (score -1):

Yes it can, you can use the method [stashedFile](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/)

```
parameters([
  string(name: "Name", defaultValue: "val", description: "description"),
  stashedFile(name: "name", description: "description")
])
```

and later access it using the `unstash` method and pass it the value that was passed to the `name` argument of `stashedFile`